# EIP-712: practical usage of the verifyingContract in the eip712Domain structure

Tags: signature, ecrecover, ecdsa, eip, eip712

Is the `verifyingContract` field in the `eip712Domain` used *anywhere* *practically*, e.g. calling to verify the signature, etc. etc.? Or is it just another protection trick for signature replay attacks?

---

**Here's what the docs say, but I want to confirm:**

> **Definition of domainSeparator.** `domainSeparator = hashStruct(eip712Domain)` where the type of `eip712Domain` is a struct
> named `EIP712Domain` with one or more of the below fields. *Protocol
> designers only need to include the fields that make sense for their
> signing domain. Unused fields are left out of the struct type.*

- `string name` the user readable name of signing domain, i.e. the name of the DApp or the protocol.
- `string version` the current major version of the signing domain. Signatures from different versions are not compatible.
- `uint256 chainId` the EIP-155 chain id. The user-agent should refuse signing if it does not match the currently active chain.
- `address verifyingContract` the address of the contract that will verify the signature. The user-agent may do contract specific phishing prevention.
- `bytes32 salt` an disambiguating salt for the protocol. This can be used as a domain separator of last resort.

---

*P.S.* What I mean is whether it's used as per the standard specification *(not custom code implementations)*

*(Reference: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712#definition-of-domainseparator)*

Comment: What do you mean by "practical usage"? It is not "just another protection trick", but a crucial component to protect signers from replay attacks, similar to the chainId, but at the contract level. Additionally the wallets, for example, [Rabby](https://github.com/RabbyHub/Rabby/blob/dc1c2aa8a455f8d82a147536c0c1d589413502cf/src/ui/views/Approval/components/TypedDataActions/utils.ts#L98), explicitly shows the user which contract they are signing a message for, thereby protecting against phishing attacks.

Comment: Thank you!! You answered my question. *What I initially meant to ask in my question is* **whether there's any extension to the `EIP-712` standard that makes calls to the `verifyingContract` like `ERC-1271` does**, *for instance*. That's just what the name of the field (`verifyingContract`) immediately made me think about. *But now taking another look at it, I understand that there's probably supposed to be a check during decoding, **whether `verifyingContract` `==` `address(this)`**.* Am I correct?

Comment: It checks indirectly by using `address(this)`  in DomainSeparator: e.g.  the permit implementation by OpenZeppelin: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/8cc7f2dcbf368f2a7ea491389dae41f01c16e352/contracts/utils/cryptography/EIP712.sol#L89

Comment: Aah, got it, thank you for explaining well!